# Selenium WebDriver. Select element from div list

Tags: java, select, selenium-webdriver

I have the following area on the `HTML` page:

```
<div class="t2-selector">  
    <div class="">  
        USA  
        <div>  
            <div>  
                <div>  
                    <div class="selected" asset-id="129">Google</div>  
                    <div asset-id="130">Microsoft</div>  
                    <div asset-id="126">Apple</div>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
       </div>  
</div>  
<div class="inactive">  
    Europe  
    <div>  
        <div>  
            <div>  
                <div class="inactive" asset-id="127">BT</div>  
            </div>  
        </div>  
   </div>  
</div>  
<div class="">  
    Currencies  
    <div>  
        <div>  
            <div>  
                <div asset-id="135">EUR/USD</div>  
                    <div asset-id="136" class="">GBP/USD</div>  
                    <div asset-id="137" class="">USD/JPY</div>  
                    <div asset-id="138" class="selected">USD/CHF</div>  
                    <div asset-id="139">AUD/USD</div>  
                    <div asset-id="140">USD/CAD</div>  
                </div>  
            </div>  
       </div>  
</div>
```

So I need to select desired element from one of the groups (that should not be inactive, OK).
When I'm selecting a group nothing occurs, no error and I don't see the the selected group opens. 
Even for a moment.
But when I'm trying to select an element in previously clicked group I receive

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
```

error.
So I understand that in the moment I'm clicking on desired element it is not visible since the group not appears open.
But why?
And what can I do to resolve this problem?
Currently I'm using following code:

```
String selectedGroup = getValue("group",'o');  
    String xpath1 = "//div[contains(text(),'" + selectedGroup + "')]";  
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath1)).click();  
    webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath1));  
    String className = webElement.getAttribute("class");  
    if(className.contentEquals("inactive"))  
        throw new ElementInactiveException("Selected group appears inactive. Exiting the test");  

    String optionAssetID = getValue("assetID",'o');  
    String xpath2 ="//div[@asset-id='" + optionAssetID + "']";  

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath2)).click();
```

the error occur on the following line:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath2)).click();
```

When clicking on a Group or hovering over it it looks in the following way:
As you can see from the code the selected / opened group receives "group-visible" class parameter.

[image: When clicked on a Group or hovered over it it looks so:]

Comment: At which line in your code do you receive this error?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath2)).click();

Comment: You mention about group not opening. What are the groups here. It might be better to paste a screenshot - obviously there is some scripting happening that we cannot see.

Comment: Screenshot and additional explanations are added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hover over the drop down to open it and then click on your element

```
// simulate mouse movement to the dropdown 
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath1))).perform();

// wait for the element to be visible before clicking on it
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(xpath2)).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to click using JavascriptExecutor

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("Your Xpath"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I will try this when I'm back to the work. Currently I'm ill at home :(